# Is it possible to configure/extend log4net to stop loging the same exception during an extended outage?

Tags: .net, logging, log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-filter

We have a distributed micro service application using log4net with a custom appender in production. 
The problem is that during an outage on any external system or service, or even during a small hiccup in our Token provider service, for every user trying to hit that service we get one or several repeated logs, multiply that for all users and we get over 20000 repeated logs in 15 minutes overflowing our quota.

We want to stop spamming our log with this without adding catching to the c# micro services if possible.

I tried filtering specific logs but log4net's filtering only works positively, like so:

I want to filter logs with the word "Token" in them:

```
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.StringMatchFilter">
        <acceptOnMatch value="false" />
        <stringToMatch value="Token" />
    </filter>
```

But..errors messages with "Token" are still logged :(

Peculiarly, with the following filter:

```
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.StringMatchFilter">
        <acceptOnMatch value="**true**" />
        <stringToMatch value="Token" />
    </filter>
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter" />
```

Only messages that contain the string "Token" are logged (OK, it's the behavior that I would hope)

And with the following filter:

```
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.StringMatchFilter">
        <acceptOnMatch value="false" />
        <stringToMatch value="Token" />
    </filter>
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter" />
```

No message is recorded in log (OK, it's the behavior that I would hope)

The entry in Apaches documentation for AcceptOnMatch:

> "The AcceptOnMatch property is a flag that determines the behavior when a matching Level is found. If the flag is set to true then the filter will Accept the logging event, otherwise it will **Neutral** the event."

So how is it Denied? Is this behavior even possible? any ideas?

Sorry for the length of this post, any possible solution to my original problem is most welcome, be it for this filtering problem or an alternative to avoid spamming the logs.

Thanks a lot for reading!

Comment: Not aware of anything in log4net but if that's only one place, I'd manually code a "dead-time" - maybe with a counter, so I can log for example "20000 x Exception Blah Blah occured since 11:00 today"  ...

Comment: Thanks Fildor, in our environment this isnt really the best option, something configurable would be ideal. Log4Net is currently configured to log all exceptions, and the exceptions are not handled in a way we can do this, they are bubbled up by each micro service and logged by log4net. In order to do what you propose we would have to change every micro service to identify an external service is down (we consume several) and to handle that in a specific way, its not really the best solution to make the services more complex.

Comment: Besides we might want to enable logs from this kinds of exceptions later, so something configurable like log4net filters is the best option.